# Mobile performance testing for Android

Tags: mobile, angular

What tools can be used to test a mobile app in Android that was built using Angular 2? Is there any tool for testing performance like load, speed etc.  for mobile apps?

Comment: Please edit your question to give more detail: as it stands the question is far too broad and could be answered by "fingers and a working brain". You can read https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more information about what makes a good question.